# Swift 3 (SpriteKit): SKShapeNode not moving when its image is changed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have come across an issue with SKShapeNodes that I'm struggling to understand. To help explain and show my problem, I have created a test program. At the start I create a line like this:

```
var points = [CGPoint(x: -372, y: 0), CGPoint(x: 372, y: 0)]
var Line = SKShapeNode(points: &points, count: points.count)
addChild(Line)
```

At this point, I am able to change the position of the node, and it prints the position I expect it to be:

```
Line.position.y = Line.position.y - 50
print("LINEPOS =", Line.position)
```

It prints:

> LINEPOS = (0.0, -50.0)

This makes sense because the SKShapeNode's original position is always (0, 0). However, the next part of the program doesn't work in the same way. I make the new points equal the coordinates of where the Line is now on the screen, and let the Line equal them like this:

```
points = [CGPoint(x: -372, y: -50), CGPoint(x: 372, y: -50)]
Line = SKShapeNode(points: &points, count: points.count)
```

Then I change the position of the Line again (this time I moved it down by 200 so the change in position is more noticeable) like this:

```
Line.position.y = Line.position.y - 200
print("LINEPOS =", Line.position)
```

It prints:

> LINEPOS = (0.0, -200.0)

Even though it prints the position correctly, it is clear that the Line hasn't moved at all on the screen. It is still at the same position as it was when I let the line equal the new points. This means that after letting the SKShapeNode equal a new set of points, it no longer moves on the screen but in the code it says it does.

How can I fix this? If anyone knows please help because I'm really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene:SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    var points = [CGPoint(x: -372, y: 0), CGPoint(x: 372, y: 0)]
    var Line = SKShapeNode(points: &points, count: points.count)
    addChild(Line)

    Line.position.y = Line.position.y - 50
    print("LINEPOS =", Line.position)

    points = [CGPoint(x: -372, y: -50), CGPoint(x: 372, y: -50)]
    Line.removeFromParent()

    Line = SKShapeNode(points: &points, count: points.count)
     addChild(Line)
    Line.position.y = Line.position.y - 200
    print("LINEPOS =", Line.position)

    }
}
```

From your code, when you for the second time do something like `Line = SKShapeNode = ...` the new shape is created, which doesn't have a parent yet. It is not in a node tree. What you are seeing is the old shape, which is not removed from a parent. So, remove that one, and add a new one... Or, don't create a new shape every time, and just change its position.

Also, this can be a bit confusing. Even if you remove the line which says:

```
Line.removeFromParent()
```

the code will compile (but you will see two  lines).

So, even though you are working on a same variable and a fact that a node can have only one parent, the code still compiles if you don't remove the Line from parent, before you make another `addChild(Line)` call. How is that possible?

Well, that works because of this:

1. You create a Line which is a reference to a `SKShapeNode` which is added to a parent right after its creation. Now, because it is added to a tree, there is another reference pointing to it, because it is a part of a scene's `children` array.
2. Then you instantiate a Line variable again, so now it shows on a different `SKShapeNode` in memory (but the old `SKShapeNode` is still in a tree). This new SKShapeNode is not added to a tree, and its parent proprety is a nil. Because of this, you can add it again to a tree, without having compiler yelling at you.

**EDIT:**

To respond to your comments about how to change a path of an SKShapeNode, you could do something like this:

let path = CGMutablePath()

```
points = [CGPoint(x: -372, y: -250), CGPoint(x: 372, y: -250)]

path.move(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y))

path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: points[1].x, y: points[1].y))

Line.path = path
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Now I understand it much better. So are you suggesting that removing the node and then adding a new one is the best way to change the image of the node?

Comment: So when before I change the value of the skshapenode again, I must remove it from its parent?

Comment: @J.Treutlein It really depends what you are trying to do. It is not a must of course it is not a rule. But in  your case, to get desired effects, yeah, you have to do that.

Comment: @J.Treutlein Personally, I don't know why do you re-create a node again? You shouldn't re-instantiate a complete node just to change its position. Not a performant way to go.

Comment: Because I wanted to change the image of the node (in other words: make it look different).

Comment: @J.Treutlein The image ? You mean the `fillTexture` or strokeTexture`? Because `SKShapeNode` doesn't have a `texture` property like `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: In my case: I wanted to change the path of the line so it went through different points

Comment: @J.Treutlein So change just `path` property :)

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @J.Treutlein Checkout the edit. Also, as I pointed out in one of your previous questions, it is better idea for the future readers to ask new things in a separate questions instead in comments ;)

Comment: Thanks so much that helps :)

Comment: my problem now using that code is that since I never let Line equal something, its value is nil and I can't add a child with this value. How can I fix this?

Comment: @J.Treutlein You should initialize it once. I said you dont have to do that multiple times. So, 1) create shape node, 2) add it to a scene, 3) change its path (multiple times)

Comment: Never mind about that question i think I figured it out. But, now whenever I change the path it looks like it creates new lines and they are not in the correct position.

Comment: @J.Treutlein With the code I gave you? It works for me... Copy and paste it to check. Or maybe I got you wrong about what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: No I'm pretty sure you know what I want to do. My code looks like this at the start: `points = [CGPoint(x: -372, y: -250), CGPoint(x: 372, y: -250)]                     Line = SKShapeNode(path: path)                                                         addChild(Line)`

Comment: Then I keep repeating this throughout the program whilst changing the value of points:                                                                          `path.move(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y))                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: points[1].x, y: points[1].y))                                      Line.path = path`

Comment: I also forgot to say that I initialise Line as an optional variable like this: `Line: SKShapeNode? = nil` so it is defined for all functions

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the issue where it seemed like there were so many duplicates of the line by adding `path = CGMutablePath()` before adding a new path in order to reset the path before adding a new one each iteration. However, the new paths are still off centre and I'm still still trying to figure out how to fix it. It also seems a bit laggy but every other action is fine.

Comment: @J.Treutlein Wait I dont get. Are you working on multiple paths or a single one? I mean do you have multiple lines on a screen at the same time or just one ?

Comment: Don't worry I figured it out. It was a problem with my program that doesn't directly relate to this.

Answer (score 0):

just check this once

```
import SpriteKit
    var Line:SKShapeNode!
    class GameScene: SKScene {
        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
            /* Setup your scene here */
            var points = [CGPoint(x: -372, y: 0), CGPoint(x: 372, y: 0)]
           Line = SKShapeNode(points: &points, count: points.count)
            addChild(Line)

        }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
           /* Called when a touch begins */
           Line.position.y = Line.position.y + 200

        }

        override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
            /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I specifically have the issue after I set the skshapenode to something different after the first time. That is when the skshapenode doesn't move on the screen.

Comment: @dragoneye The problem is that OP instantiates a Line variable multiple times. Look at my example.

Comment: sorry i think i am taking it wrong way whirlwind is right you need to remove child from the parent hierarchy  and assign a new value to it